# How to use variables as Node.js PUT request's json body

Tags: node.js, node-request

I'm new to programing and wanted to use the output from a child process as variable name, and this is how I failed:

```
var payload = outPutFromChildProcess;

{
    var red = '{"sat": 254,"xy": [0.68,0.31]}';
    var white = '{"ct":0}';
    request({
                method: 'PUT',
                uri: 'http://192.168.2.17/api/*****',
                json: JSON.stringify(payload) 
            },  (e, r, b) => {
                if(e)return console.error("Bridge unreachable");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(b[0].success));
            });
}
```

I know it's very wrong on many level, and I'm deeply sorry for letting you read it.
But how do I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

install axios: `npm i axios`

then:

```
const payload = { "sat": 254,"xy": [0.68,0.31] };
const config = { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} };

(async () => {
    const res = await axios.put('http://192.168.2.17/api/*****', payload, config);
})();
```